# Firebase Firestore on Android (Java): How much and what kind of requests are here?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I suspect that Firestore counts every calling of method as requests.

Let's take a simple example:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("users").document("myawesome@email.com").collection("Sets").document("MainSet").set("Important data");
```

Does every "collection" calling is a reading request?

Can you count the number of requests (reading and writing) in this sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building DocumentReference and CollectionReference objects do not cost anything.  They are just objects that contains paths to collections and documents.  None of the code you're showing costs any document reads.  Only the call to `set()` will cost 1 document write.

Comment: Thank you! But what if I use `set()` for complex objects instead of strings? Is it still costs 1 document write?

Comment: One document change is only one document.  It doesn't matter what's in that document.